# Multiple plots on same figure with DataFrame.Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

While I can get multiple lines on a chart and multiple bars on a chart - I cannot get a line and bar on the same chart using the same PeriodIndex.

Faux code follows ...

```
# play data
n = 100
x = pd.period_range('2001-01-01', periods=n, freq='M')
y1 = (Series(np.random.randn(n)).diff() + 5).tolist()
y2 = (Series(np.random.randn(n)).diff()).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'bar':y2, 'line':y1}, index=x)

# let's plot
plt.figure()
ax = df['bar'].plot(kind='bar', label='bar')
df['line'].plot(kind='line', ax=ax, label='line')
plt.savefig('fred.png', dpi=200)
plt.close()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: I love stack overflow - a serious question: I want a line and bar on the same chart, and I cannot see what my code is doing wrong (the bar chart doesn't get added). And for that I get a down vote? Also, a title change so that the question no longer reflects my information need. The code above works fine for multiple line charts and multiple bar charts - my problem is one of each.

Comment: I can't speak to why you got a downvote, but I do notice you relied on the title to portray what was wrong with what you posted.  I think more descriptive text other than, 'here's the code, please fix it' in the actual question would have been better/clearer.

Comment: I appreciate this a world inhabited by social misfits and petty tyrants. Have added the question to make clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: bar plots don't use index values as x axis, but use `range(0, n)`. You can use `twiny()` to create a second axes that share yaxis with the bar axes, and draw line curve in this second axes.

The most difficult thing is how to align x-axis ticks. Here we define the align function, which will align `ax2.get_xlim()[0]` with `x1` in `ax1` and `ax2.get_xlim()[1]` with `x2` in `ax1`:

```
def align_xaxis(ax2, ax1, x1, x2):
    "maps xlim of ax2 to x1 and x2 in ax1"
    (x1, _), (x2, _) = ax2.transData.inverted().transform(ax1.transData.transform([[x1, 0], [x2, 0]]))
    xs, xe = ax2.get_xlim()
    k, b = np.polyfit([x1, x2], [xs, xe], 1)
    ax2.set_xlim(xs*k+b, xe*k+b)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np
n = 50
x = pd.period_range('2001-01-01', periods=n, freq='M')
y1 = (Series(np.random.randn(n)) + 5).tolist()
y2 = (Series(np.random.randn(n))).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'bar':y2, 'line':y1}, index=x)

# let's plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
ax1 = df['bar'].plot(kind='bar', label='bar')
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
df['line'].plot(kind='line', label='line', ax=ax2)
ax2.grid(color="red", axis="x")

def align_xaxis(ax2, ax1, x1, x2):
    "maps xlim of ax2 to x1 and x2 in ax1"
    (x1, _), (x2, _) = ax2.transData.inverted().transform(ax1.transData.transform([[x1, 0], [x2, 0]]))
    xs, xe = ax2.get_xlim()
    k, b = np.polyfit([x1, x2], [xs, xe], 1)
    ax2.set_xlim(xs*k+b, xe*k+b)

align_xaxis(ax2, ax1, 0, n-1)
```

and the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - you have helped me enormously with this answer - I now understand what the issue was.